# Disable Disk Check at boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

I scheduled a disk check, but I had no idea it would last so long (bad sectors check, too), and that I wouldn't be able to cancel it.

Safe mode takes forever, too. I can get into the "repair your computer" screen, though. But if I run regedit from there, the key BootExecute isn't present.

I can't let it run since power goes out here every two hours for half an hour.

Is there a way to disable it from the command prompt in the repair your computer screen?

Edit: I tried running `chkntfs /x c:`. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually exit (interrupt) CHKDSK by pressing CTRL+C while it is running. Also there's that setting in registry, wchich allows you to turn off completely autocheck for a particular drive:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager

In the right hand pane, double click BootExecute. The default value of the key is

**autocheck autochk *****

Just add /K:C at the end before *. /K switch will disable autocheck on C: drive at Windows startup. So the final value should look like this:

**autocheck autochk /k:C *****

Comment: I had to load a hive file in the repair screen and modify that, somehow the registry in that screen was different from the normal Windows registry (it didn't have `BootExecute`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply delete the `BootExecute` (`Autocheck Autochk *`) key to disable disk check at boot here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
```